# Why does Object provide equals and hash code methods?

Tags: java, c#, language-agnostic

Many object-oriented programming languages where something like `Object` is the root of the type hierarchy provide some default equality and hash code methods; for example:

- C# `System.Object`: `Equals` and `GetHashCode`
- Java `java.lang.Object`: `equals` and `hashCode`

It is valuable to override these methods for objects that exhibit value semantics; for example, `Boolean`, `Integer` and `Guid`, but it is uncommon to override these methods for objects that exhibit behaviour semantics; for example services and controllers. These methods also serve as the mechanism to determine duplicates for `Set<T>` and `Map<K, V>` insertion.

Let's assume that `Object` does not contain these methods, and instead they are provided by interfaces; for example:

```
interface Equatable<T> {
    Boolean equals(T other)
}

interface Hashable {
    Integer getHashCode()
}
```

Now, objects that exhibit behaviour semantics don't implement the methods because they're not required, but objects that exhibit value semantics can implement them; for example:

```
class Guid : Equatable<Guid>, Hashable {
    public Boolean equals(Guid other) {
        ...
    }

    public Integer getHashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also `Set<T>` and `Map<K, V>` could declare constraints on `T` and `K`, such that objects should implement `Equatable<T>` and `Hashable`; for example:

```
interface Set<T> where T extends Equatable<T>, Hashable {
    ...
}

interface Map<K, V> where K extends Equatable<T>, Hashable {
    ...
}
```

Given that not all objects (i.e. those that exhibit behaviour semantics) require these methods to be overridden, it seems plausible that equals and hash code methods did not need to be declared at the root of the type hierarchy, so why **are** they defined at the root of the type hierarchy, rather than something expected to be implemented as required?

Is there some other underlying or fundamental reason that these methods are implemented at the root of the type hierarchy, and are there any *similar* languages where this isn't the case?

Comment: In the first version of C#, there were no generics. Maybe that is a reason why the language designers thought it would be easier to add the equals and gethashcode method to the object class.

Comment: At least in Java, objects have a default equality (i.e., reference equality). It makes sense to me for `Object` to define `equals`. And given `equals` and `hashCode` are inherently related, it makes sense to me for `Object` to define the latter method as well.

Comment: @SomeBody That's a good point. I believe the same is true for Java. On that basis, would you consider that a hypothetical new programming language that did include generics from the start could be designed such that `equals` and `getHashCode` could be implemented via interfaces instead?

Comment: Yes. That's what Swift did. See the Swift protocols [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) and [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable).

Comment: @Slaw The same is true for C#, where `Equals` defaults to reference equality, but in C#, there is also a static `Object.ReferenceEquals`, so it seems unnecessary.

Comment: For Java: Consider a class like `HashSet`. First it buckets based on `hashCode`, then checks for duplicates via `equals`. This needed to work pre-generics. In other words, `HashSet` needed to be able to work with any class. With scenarios like that, it makes sense for these methods to be defined by `Object`. There may be other solutions, though I don't think they'd be as clean. But I think perhaps if Java always had generics, then an interface such as `Equatable` would have made sense.

Comment: @user16320675 It needs both `Hashable` and `Equatable`. So, either they'd need a combined interface, or have both methods defined in the root of the hierarchy.

Comment: The default implementations of hashCode and equals are valid, useful, and commonly used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no fundamental reason they *have* to be implemented at the root, for all the reasons you mention. This answer will be specifically for c#, but I would guess many of the arguments apply to java as well.

We can only speculate why the language designers used this model, but it is likely influenced by the lack of generics in the first version of C#. Influence from java, that also lacked generics, may also have played a part. Note that in c# your proposed interface does exist in the form of [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-8.0).

However If I understand your argument correctly, `HashSet` would be constrained to `IEquatable<T>`. This would only be implemented for types using value equality. Therefore `HashSet` could not be used with types using reference equality, and this seem like an obvious problem. Dictionaries and HashSets are still very useful for objects using reference equality.

That is not to say I think the equality system, as it is now, is well designed. To compare two objects you may use

1. `.Equals(object obj)`
2. `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T obj)`
3. Equality operators, `==` / `!=`, (and each of these require explicit implementation)
4. `IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals(T a, T b)`

This is confusing for new developers, and tend to lead to a quite significant amount of boiler plate code. This, as many other things, is partially due to the language evolution. New features have to be carefully designed work with existing code. If c# where rewritten from scratch you could almost certainly make improvements, and that would likely include removal or redesign of `.Equals(object obj)`. But that is not really feasible since it would break decades of existing code.

If you are designing a new language please *do* consider ways to handle equality better. But I would expect this to require some major design work to make it as easy to understand and use as possible while still allowing for necessary flexibility. Designing languages is not easy! Looking around at other languages there are several that has problems in the equality area, C# is at least better than [javascript](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/).

As for similar languages, both java and c# where in some sense intended as an easier to use c++. And that just avoid the problem by not having a common type root at all. But there are some usability downsides with that approach.

Comment: I give it an up "That is not to say I think the equality system in C# is well designed." but don't like that wording. It was pretty well designed then it evolved with new ideas and you get concurrent concepts for the same thing because you can't simply remove the superseded concepts that easily.  Only in the rear view mirror it looks like a design problem. No its an evolution problem.

Comment: @Ralf fair point, I made some updates. But I would argue some features, like `!=` not being automatically implemented as `!(a == b)`, was poor design from the beginning. So I would still argue it is not *only* due to evolution of the language.